# Compactness of intersections of arbitrary sets in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

For $\:$$n$ $\in$ $\mathbf{N}$,$\:$let$\ E_{n}$ be a closed set.  $\:$Let's also let $\:$$ a,b \in\mathbf{R}$ such that$\ E_{1}\subset\:[\:a, b\:]$

Show that $\:E=\large\bigcap\limits_{n\in\mathbf{N}}$$E_{n}$ $\:$ is compact.

So basically I'm a newcomer to real analysis and I do not know how to have a great start whilst I hop into this proof, so that  any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: it seems some folks believe this question has already been answered. I went en read that very question that may have similarities with this one, but I must say the main differences lain here are such that there is possibly an infinite intersection of closed sets, whilst the aforementioned question works with two sets.

Hey thanks

Comment: What is your definition of "compact"?

Comment: Can you use Heine-Borel, or do you need to prove it directly from the definition of compactness, which is  a finite subcover?

Comment: Well a set would be compact if for every open cover of that very set there exists a finite subcover

Comment: We need to show directly from the definition of compactness that E is indeed compact

Comment: I sure could have solved this the way you suggest, but since I'm new to this field of study I didn't have that intuition about all proporties of closed sets. Anyway thanks for the hint : every tips like this one you just gave I take into account to better my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use the definition of compactness that says every open cover has a finite subcover.

Since $E_{n}$ is closed for each $n$, and countable intersections of closed sets are closed (why?), then $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}$ is closed.

Ok, well let $\cup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$ be an open cover of $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}$.  Since $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}$ is closed, $\Bbb R - \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}$ is open.

Then $(\cup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}) \cup (\Bbb R - \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n})$ is an open cover for $[a,b]$ (why?).  Find a finite subcover of this new cover for $[a,b]$ (since $[a,b]$ is compact).  This will give us a finite subcover for the original cover, which covers $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}$ (why?).